# Nagios - Could not open command file /usr/local/nagios/var/rw/nagios.cmd’ for update

Tags: monitoring, nagios

I'm trying to disable active check for a service through Nagios web interface, but I cant make it.
The Nagios instance is running on a Centos 5 distribution

Each time I try to stop the service I get this message : 
Could not open command file ‘/usr/local/nagios/var/rw/nagios.cmd’ for update!

Although I tried several proposals found on the web :

```
usermod -a -G nagios apache
chmod 666 /usr/local/nagios/var/rw/nagios.cmd
chown nagios.nagcmd /usr/local/nagios/var/rw
chmod u+rwx /usr/local/nagios/var/rw
chmod g+rwx /usr/local/nagios/var/rw  
chmod g+s /usr/local/nagios/var/rw
```

Each time rebooting nagios service afterwards of course.

Thanks for your help !
Cheers

Comment: What are the nagios_user and nagios_group [config values](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/configmain.html#nagios_user)  set to?  What are the latest permissions on nagios.cmd and each of the directories on the way down to it?

Comment: nagios_user and nagios_group are both set to nagios. Permissions on nagios.cmd are `prw-rw---- nagios nagcmd`. thx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This command is wrong:

> usermod -a -G nagios apache

The group permissions on your rw directory and nagios.cmd file are nagcmd, not nagios. You need this, instead:

> usermod -a -G nagcmd apache

This is what worked for me - or more specifically, on Ubuntu, it's:

> usermod -a -G nagios www-data

Comment: For people passing by. I fixed mine by

`usermod -a -G nagios,nagcmd www-data`

in _Debian_

Answer (score 9):

Selinux can also cause this problem. You can check its status with:

```
sestatus
```

If current mode is enforcing, change it to permissive with:

```
setenforce 0
```

Then you may be able to commit your changes into nagios.cmd.

Comment: Looks like indeed SELinux enforcing mode has been causing me nagios.cmd issues, as suggested here. Any idea of how to make the Nagios command interface work consistently with enforcing mode enabled?

Answer (score 6):

This is how you have to follow

```
service httpd stop

service nagios stop


usermod -G nagcmd nagios

usermod -G nagcmd apache

chown nagios:nagcmd /usr/local/nagios/var/rw

chown nagios:nagcmd /usr/local/nagios/var/rw/nagios.cmd


service httpd start

service nagios start
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should fix the issue in Debian:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /usr/local/nagios/var/
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this mentioned and it caught me out, it's worth checking the apache child processes are running as the apache user.

I built my apache from source and this uses daemon as the default user and group for the child processes so this had to be changed for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is :

```
chmod ugo+rw /usr/local/nagios/var/rw/ /usr/local/nagios/var/rw/nagios.cmd
```

and restarting apache and nagios.

Answer (score -1):

The only issue with this is selinux. 
Stop it and it will work fine. Credit goes to Nagios team.